# Setting values of a dictionary while creating it

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I was trying to set the values according to the keys of the dictionary, while creating the dictionary itself.

I can do it with an additional step, but is there a way to do the following:

```
dictionary = {
    'a': 'Key of this = ' + dictionary.key(),
    'b': 'Key of this = ' + dictionary.key(),
    'c': 'Key of this = ' + dictionary.key(),
}
```

Expected outcome would be then:

```
>>>dictionary
{
    'a': 'Key of this = a',
    'b': 'Key of this = b',
    'c': 'Key of this = c',
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the dictionary using a comprehension:

```
>>> {key: f"Key of this = {key}" for key in ('a', 'b', 'c')}
{'a': 'Key of this = a', 'b': 'Key of this = b', 'c': 'Key of this = c'}
```

Comment: works thank you, I will be able to accept it in 12 mins